# journal_async_commit is not compatible with older kernels. What would you see in this case?

Tags: linux, ext4

[`man ext4`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/ext4.5.html) mentions a mount option called `journal_async_commit`.

> Commit block can be written to disk without waiting for descriptor blocks. **If enabled older kernels cannot  mount  the  device.**  This will enable 'journal_checksum' internally.

Caveat: the document is incomplete.  1) The option is also no longer allowed in combination with the default option `data=ordered`.  2) As of 2012, the option was considered "off the reservation a bit; that's really not tested, and Jan had serious reservations about its safety".  I do not know if the option is any more mature in current kernel versions.

Overall this limits its usefulness somewhat.  So I don't have a specific practical use for this question.  Perhaps someone else is interested in it though.

Q1. What sort of message would appear in the kernel log, if an old kernel is unable to support mounting a filesystem, and the failure reason is that the filesystem had previously been mounted with `journal_async_commit`?  Would it be possible to identify this specific problem?

Q2. I assume that old kernels will still be able to mount the filesystem if the journal is cleaned/empty, for example if you run a new enough version of `fsck.ext4` first.  (`fsck.ext4` is documented as replaying the journal).  If I run the current versions of `tune2fs` or `debuge2fs` on an unmounted filesystem, will they show a specific incompatible feature flag, that would tell me exactly whether a too-old kernel can or cannot mount it?

Q3. Is it possible to enable `journal_async_commit` using `tune2fs` (and `mkfs.ext4`)?  If so, what will `tune2fs -l` show when it is enabled?

I think the current answer to Q3 is that `tune2fs` can set default mount options.  `journal_async_commit` is *not* documented as an option that can be set with `tune2fs -o`.  Therefore you would have to resort to `tune2fs -E mount_opts=journal_async_commit`.  This feature is not "very polished"; it seems that if you want to set more than one option in `mount_opts=` you must [use debuge2fs instead](https://serverfault.com/questions/898724/how-to-pass-multiple-options-to-tune2fs-e-mount-opts).